# If partial string in the same pandas column match then update the value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame from this CSV file. [image: CSV]

I have several of these files that I'm combining into one large file. I need to iterate over the player column, and if one cell partially matches the corresponding CPTN cell, then I need to update the Pos value for the player cell containing CPTN to be CPTN + '(POS)'.

The final results would look something like this:

```
Bryce Mitchell        WR
Bryant Koback         RB
Bryant Koback CPTN    CPTN (RB)
Bryce Mitchell CPTN   CPTN (WR)
```

Here is a spreadsheet to test: [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JP-cf4jmFm5RtyBFSGEGhu0ttmYvu2eGsQZnVu2w4ao/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slightly adjusted the data so we can see one who didn't play CPTN

```
df
###
                Player   Pos  Salary
0       Bryce Mitchell    WR    6400
1        Bryant Koback    RB   10200
2   Bryant Koback CPTN  CPTN   15300
3  Bryce Mitchell CPTN  CPTN    9600
4      Jordan Legendre    QB   23450
```

```
temp = df.copy()
temp['Player'] = temp['Player'].str.replace(' CPTN', '')
temp_g = temp.groupby('Player')['Pos'].apply(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=' ')).reset_index()
temp_g['Player'] = np.where(temp_g['Pos'].str.contains('CPTN'), temp_g['Player'] + ' CPTN', temp_g['Player'])
temp_g['Pos'] = np.where(temp_g['Pos'].str.contains('CPTN'), 'CPTN (' + temp_g['Pos'].str.replace('CPTN', '').str.strip() + ')', temp_g['Pos'])
temp_g = temp_g[temp_g['Player'].str.contains('CPTN')]
df['Pos'] = np.where(df['Player'].str.contains('CPTN'), df['Player'].map(temp_g.set_index('Player')['Pos']), df['Pos'])
df
###
                Player        Pos  Salary
0       Bryce Mitchell         WR    6400
1        Bryant Koback         RB   10200
2   Bryant Koback CPTN  CPTN (RB)   15300
3  Bryce Mitchell CPTN  CPTN (WR)    9600
4      Jordan Legendre         QB   23450
```

Answer (score 1):

an idea will be to update over a mask:

```
cptn_mask = df['Player'].str.contains('CPTN')
df.loc[cptn_mask , 'Player'] = "CPTN" + df.loc[cptn_mask , 'Position']
```